# overflow:scroll prevents slider gif from displaying

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, gif

I've added a floating gif with a slide out form to capture lead information. it works great but with lower resolution screen the form gets cut off so I though of adding a scroll bar. But when I add a scroll bar to the form the gif does not become visible.

Css being used

```
/*slide-out-div */
 .slide-out-div {overflow:scroll;padding: 20px;background: #ccc; border:1px solid black;width:250px;}
```

Html form

```
<div class="slide-out-div">
```

web site: www.dealerclick.com

Comment: I would try either make the form fields shorter vertically or setting a fixed height to your div tall enough to always show the gif.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, as I'm sure you know, is that you have the "handle" absolute positioned negatively to the right of the form container. So when you set overflow to auto (or scroll) as I assume you were, it will hide the handle.

This is not an error, it's the way css is supposed to work. Although there are a couple ways you can solve this, I think the best way is to add `overflow: auto` to `.slide-out-div form` so that only the form has the scroll bars (when you do this, you will see that your set width was too narrow as well).

Setting overflow to auto is the way to go here because setting overflow to scroll forces the scrollbars even when they are not necessary, which is not good ux practice.

This is all good and well, but the other problem here is that when you set `overflow: auto` and the page is not tall enough, since the div has a fixed position, it still won't work the way you want. So really the best way to take care of this issue is to use a little JS to detect window height, like this:

```
var window_height = window.innerHeight;
if (window_height < 668) {
   $('.slide-out-div form').css('overflow', 'scroll');
}
```

What this does is check if the window height is too small to display the full height of the form plus it's offset from the top (which on your page is 668px), and if so, adds the scroll bars. If not, no scroll bars and no problems.

Comment: Jeff, I would like to implement your JS solution but I must be missing a piece here. Where would I drop this piece of code in? I know this sounds stupid...

Comment: Hey, did you get this to work? More specifically, you need to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the page, then put the code snippet I provided between `<script>` tags below.

Comment: Thanks for the additional help I will try after the holiday. I the short term I re-sized the form to fit into 800X600 rez